# Mirroring Blender 3.0 is not doing what I want it to do? How to get them into the right place?

Tags: mirror, empty

I want to get the bed legs from the left to be mirrored to the right.
Whenever I try the legs don't get on the right spot
[image]

[image]

Whenever I add a mirror modifier and click Y then they are in the middel of the bed.
I first thoughted the red X was not in the middle, moved the whole screen so the red X is in the middle but after then I want to mirror it just gets in te wrong spot. Is it remembering still the red X axe? I also read before I post this to move the origin, the little orange dot, but don't know how to move or where to move to, one I found said make an empty,, post was from 2016 and shift A wasn't doing anymore what I read in that post

I am just started with blender (some days) and not much experience with drawings, the youtube video I found, was too fast for me to follow and missing some information for a beginner.

[image]

In advance thanks for your answer

All the best
Esa69

[image]

[image: Picture 4 as solution]

Thx. I have understood following:  empty = just create a (shift a) plane and name it empty1, move (g) the empty1 to the middle of the bed, then add modifier mirror on the Y axis and it works indeed, Placed a picture 4 after your answers to explain for others.

Comment: Ps: Shift a is the shortcut key for adding any object into the scene. It should still work in 3.0.

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer, but IIRC the mirror modifier works off the object's origin...

Comment: dunnowhattocallmyself thx for your answer, At the time I read it first time (before I posted this) I could not find empty in the menu. because of your answer I understood, maybe make your own and just call it empty. Is there a better way to make emptys?

Comment: thx Ron Jensen, dont know what you mean, Googled IIRC and found here and there but dont knwo the meaning of it. What I did wrong I thinking now, is that the bed was not exact in the middel of the X axis, therefor mirror worked but not to the end of the bed but in the middel. But didnot know how to reset it without starting all over. The empty solution did work, not so nicely done if I wanted, but I am not expecting after few days of playing with blender to do all perfectly, but I got the idea how to solve this, thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with the mirror modifier in the beginning.

The most logic way to use it: just use an empty as mirror object. This should be placed where the origin is in your upper picture.
If you then use the mirror modifier:

[image]

it should work.

Explanation how the mirror modifier works without mirror object:

The object mirrors itself at its own origin point. This is very easy to understand, if you add a mirror modifier and move the object in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Thx. I have understood following:

Comment: Thx. I have understood following:  empty = just create shift a plane and name it empty1, move (g) the empty1 to the middle of the bed, then add modifier mirror on the Y axis and it works indeed, Placed a photo to explain

Comment: When I made a plane, moved it too middle of bed, you still can see the plane, so I did a move down out of sight, is there a way to make an empty which is better then my plane and move it out of sight? btw If I delete the plane then it also deletes the mirror Y axis so I couldnot delete the empty1 plane I used

Comment: You don't need to use a Plane! To add an Empty to the scene, use SHIFT-A and the Empty items are around halfway down the main menu with a 'Y' shaped icon, **not** on the Mesh submenu. You want the Plain Axis Empty type.

Comment: Woowww  Thx John, thats the first thing I missed, didnot see that empty in the middel, thanks mate,

Comment: @ESA69: maybe you should read the answer text more carefully next time. I wrote: "just use an empty". And in the first picture you can clearly see in "mirror object": Empty

Comment: and it would be nice, if you could click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you.

Comment: @Chris Didnt see the checkmark , 
John Eason solved it for me as I didnt know whats an empty , I am like one week new with blender, so all is new for me. Didnt see checkmark for 
John Eason to use

Comment: Hi Chris , I don't agree, it wasn't clear for me what you ment, I am sorry for that and yes I did read your email several times, maybe I am too stupid, but I don't know where to find empty until John Eason said to look in the menu and search for empty see above and then with all comments I couldn't figure out where the empty was, I google always before asking, but finding or missing the point about the things I cant find or think about I use to ask the community, thank for your  friendly answer and your help is much appreciated. I wish you a wonderful day.

Comment: @Chris, Do I need to close this case somehow? For me me problem has been solved, I also documented as much possible for others to learn from my question

Comment: As I wrote: if my answer helped you, just check the checkmark left to my answer. But you don’t have to do that. Then it is not „closed“, but other can see that the answer works and helped you to do it. You can also write your own answer and check your own answer as right.